# Devanagari text rendering improperly in PyGame

Tags: python, unicode, pygame, text-rendering, devanagari

We have a small web app that we want to convert into something native. Right now, it's got a lot of moving parts (the backend, the browser etc.) and we'd like to convert it into a single tight application. We decided to use PyGame to do this and it's been fine so far except for a font rendering issue.

The string I'd like to render is कोझिकोड. This, correctly rendered looks like [image: Correctly rendered].

The specific code points are \u0915 \u094b \u091d \u093f \u0915 \u094b and \u0921

Now, this looks fine in my editor and my browser but when I try to render it in PyGame, I get this [image: Wrongly rendered]. Basically, the vowel sign  (\u093f ि) should have been on the left of the झ but it appears to its right (and to the left of the क) thereby messing it up completely. This doesn't happen in a browser or a text editor (with the same input string) so I'm guessing it a renderer problem in PyGame.

There is one crude fix which works only in this specific case which i s to put the  ि (\u093f) before the झ (\u091d). In that case, it renders properly like so [image: Crude fix]. This relies on me knowing something about the language and putting that logic into the code. I have to deal with multiple languages here so that's not really feasible.

I don't have much experience with unicode so I don't know how to approach this problem. Is there something I can do to fix this?

In case it matters, I'm using the [freesans](http://www.fontspace.com/gnu-freefont/freesans) font which is there on Debian and which has the necessary glyphs to render this.

*Update:*
The code to actually render this is as follows

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

import pygame

# Pygame setup and create root window
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 200))
empty = pygame.Surface((320, 200))


font_file = pygame.font.match_font("freesans")  # Select and
font = pygame.font.Font(font_file, 30)          # open the font
writing = font.render(u"कोिझकोड  कोझिकोड", True, (0, 0, 0))  # Render text on a surface
screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) # Clear the background
screen.blit(writing, (10, 10)) # Blit the text surface on the background
pygame.display.flip()  # Refresh the display

input() # Wait for input before quitting
```

This is what it looks like [image: Error in rendering]

The first word is rendered correctly but we've done it by inverting the vowel and the letter positions as I mentioned in the crude fix. The second is written properly but not rendered correctly.

**Update 2**:
In the absence of anything else, I've decided to try to render the string into an image using an external program and then blit this image onto the PyGame Surface. I tried imagemagick but it messes us in the same way as this. Gimp works fine and so I'm planning to use the batch mode to get my work done.

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that, years ago, a [similar bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43951) affected chromium browser.

Comment: You should open a bug report against SDL_ttf. Other font renderers get it right and it proves once more that rendering text is a non-trivial task. Unless you get SDL_ttf developers to fix this, I’m afraid your only option is to switch to a different text rendering engine (such as freetype possibly via pango or something like that).

Comment: That's where I am right now. However,  I'm really looking for a workaround right now to see whether there's some documented way I can get this to render correctly.

Comment: is it somewhat similar to this ? https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2255

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to finally resort to a really ugly but usable workaround for my own situation. I wrote a `script-fu` plugin which takes a filename and a piece of text as arguments. It then writes out the text and saves it a png file using gimp. My program then loads this up and blits the png directly onto the surface.

Answer (score 5):

I think is a SDL_ttf problem (the underlying component which actually renders the text).

While my IDE correctly renders the string

[image]

The SDL_TTF program does not:

[image]

There is the code: https://gist.github.com/ilario-pierbattista/be6b967b05fa2f1eb322f35988a33ad0

I'm still looking for a solution

Comment: That's my situation too.

Comment: This guy had the same problem and published a patch for SDL_ttf.
[Here](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=48243) the main post, [here](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3046) the bugzilla page, and [here](https://bugzilla-attachments.libsdl.org/attachment.cgi?id=2208) the patch.